# C segmentation fault when dynamically allocating 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a c program, which will take an input from Linux pipe and 
puts each word up to the point when it encounters \n into arrays. Then it outputs the words. It works when array contain less than 3 \n but it gives me segmentation error if there is 3 \n`s in the input. Here is the code that I wrote, please help. I am new to programming,so please try to live the code as intact as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int out=0;
  int in=0;
  char **arr2D;
  int i;
  int flag = 1;
  arr2D=(char**)malloc(out*sizeof(char*));
  for(i=0;i<out;i++)
    arr2D[i]=(char*)malloc(in*sizeof(char*));

  while (!feof(stdin))
    {
      in = in +1;
      arr2D[out]=(char*)realloc(arr2D[out],(in)*sizeof(char*));
      scanf("%c",&arr2D[out][i]);

      i=i+1;
      if(arr2D[out][i-1]=='\n')
        {
        out=out+1;
        arr2D=(char**)realloc(arr2D,out*sizeof(char*));
        i=0;
        in=0;
        }
    }

  int out2=0;
  int in2=0;
  do
    {
      do
        {
          printf("%c",arr2D[out2][in2]);
          in2++;
        }
      while(in2<=in-1);
      out2++;
      in2=0;
    }
  while(out2<=out);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, indent your code.

Comment: `int out=0;` : begin with a number greater than zero

Comment: [while(feof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) is a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int out = 1;
    int in = 1;
    char **arr2D;
    int i = 0;

    arr2D = malloc(out * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < out; i++)
          /* IMPORTANT */
          arr2D[i] = malloc(in * sizeof(char));

    while (!feof(stdin)) {

        scanf("%c", &arr2D[out - 1][in - 1]);

        in++;
        if (arr2D[out - 1][in - 2] == '\n') {
            arr2D[out - 1][in - 2] = '\0';
            out++;
            arr2D = realloc(arr2D, out * sizeof(char *));
            /* IMPORTANT */
            arr2D[out - 1] = NULL;
            in = 1;
        }

        /* IMPORTANT */
        arr2D[out - 1] = realloc(arr2D[out - 1],in * sizeof(char));


    }

    int out2 = 0;
    do {
        printf("%s\n", arr2D[out2++]);
    } while(out2 < out);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though that's a bug, it's definitely not the cause for the segmentation fault: `sizeof(char*)` is always greater than `sizeof(char)` (unless you are on an 8 bit architecture, that is...).

Comment: That seem not to change anything my friend.

Comment: Sorry, I still reading your code if find something I will tell you.

Comment: @cmaster there are non-8bit architectures where those sizes are equal. (Also I never heard of an 8bit architecture that didn't actually use 16bit pointers, although theoretically they're possible)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly initialized the variable `i` within your `while` loop.

```
int i;
scanf("%c",&arr2D[out][i]);
```

Comment: i is initialized at the beginning of the program, how can I initialize it in the loop and why ?

Comment: @user1335175 You declare the variable i, but you don't initialize it. For that you would need int i = 0;

Comment: As a matter of fact, he does initialize `i`: in the initialization statement of the first `for()` loop, which is executed even though the loop body is never executed...

Comment: @cmaster Whoops, didn't notice that

Comment: @cmaster Either way, though, the loop initializes it to the value of the variable 'out'. Though I'm not sure whether or not this caused the Segfault, it is a bug in its own right.

Comment: When the `scanf()` is reached for the first time, `i` is zero and `in` is one. So that's not exactly out of bounds. The out of bounds array access is in line before the `scanf()` and tries to access the first element of the zero sized array `arr2D`.

Answer (score 0):

First you allocate a buffer for `out` elements, but then you proceed to access `arr2D[out]` which is out of bounds in the first line with `realloc()`. Remember that indexing of an array `int arr[size]` in C is always from `0` to `size-1`, `arr[size]` is never ok.

For reference: the allocation line is the first `malloc()` call:

```
arr2D=(char**)malloc(out*sizeof(char*));
```

and the line with the first undefined behavior is the second line within the `while()` loop:

```
arr2D[out]=(char*)realloc(arr2D[out],(in)*sizeof(char*));
```

within the first `while()` loop. That is the point that invokes undefined behavior, and after which anything is allowed to happen.

Comment: Im note sure which part of the code you are referring to, even if I am commenting the output part, I still get the error, so I know the bug is in the part when I construct my arrays.

Comment: I added the offending lines to my answer, hope that helps you to find what I mean.

Comment: Im sorry for redundant questioning my friend, can you specify how exactly can I fix that line ? Because in my understanding, the first parameter of realloc should be the arr2D[out] itself.

Comment: First, the element at `arr2D[out]` must *exist*. That is, you first need to `realloc()` the outer array so that you have room for at least one more element. Then, and only then can you proceed to write to that new element. *The first time you get to the `realloc()` line, there is* **zero** *elements in the out  array `arr2D`*.

Comment: Oh I see what do you mean, any explanation why it works in the case when there is less than 3 \n in the input tough ?

Comment: Well, it's undefined behavior, anything can happen. Including what you expected to happen. Many implementations of `malloc()` will actually allocate a block of a certain minimal size, which can hide the bug. But you can't rely on that. The nasty thing about undefined behavior is that it generally won't crash the program right away. Instead, some other data get corrupted which you happen to overwrite with an out-of-bounds memory access, the corruption propagates silently, and strikes at a seemingly unrelated place. `valgrind` is the only tool that can effectively track down many of these bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Parham`s method seems to work, Also I found another way, altough Im not sure if there is something wrong in doing this, but it works.

Evey time when I am allocating or reallocating, I multiply the *sizeof(char) buy a buffer size which is a big number.